# Is $\int_{-a}^{a}fg^{\prime}+\int_{-a}^{a}fg^{\prime\prime}=\int_{-a}^{a}f^{\prime}g+\int_{-a}^{a}f^{\prime\prime}g$ true?

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis

Using integration by parts, I have been trying to figure out if $$\int_{-a}^{a}f(x)g^{\prime}(x)dx+\int_{-a}^{a}f(x)g^{\prime\prime}(x)dx=\int_{-a}^{a}f^{\prime}(x)g(x)dx+\int_{-a}^{a}f^{\prime\prime}(x)g(x)dx$$ is true or not, but I somehow couldn't get there. I am **not** expecting a proof or a proof that is doesn't work, but if anyone could tell me if it is true and I should continue searching that would be of great help.

Comment: No, it is not true.  Use IBP on $\int f g'$ and $\int f  g''$ to see.

Comment: Try $a=1$, $f(x)=x$, $g(x)=x^2$.

Comment: It is obviously not true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, just a quick look with Mathematica reveals:

```
In[1]:=f[x_] := Cos[x]
g[x_] := Sin[x]
a = Pi;
Integrate[f[x]*D[g[x], x], {x, -a, a}] + 
 Integrate[f[x]*D[g[x], {x, 2}], {x, -a, a}]

Out[1]=\[Pi]
```

And:

```
In[2]:=f[x_] := Cos[x]
g[x_] := Sin[x]
a = Pi;
Integrate[D[f[x], x]*g[x], {x, -a, a}] + 
 Integrate[D[f[x], {x, 2}]*g[x], {x, -a, a}]

Out[2]=-\[Pi]
```

> So, it is not true in general.

Comment: I was just asking because I'm trying to prove that $$\int_{-1}^{1}f(x)(-2x g^{\prime}(x)+(1-x^2)g^{\prime\prime}(x))dx=\int_{-1}^{1}g(x)(-2x f^{\prime}(x)+(1-x^2)f^{\prime\prime}(x))dx$$ is true, and I got really confused. Doesn't this question boil down to the question I have asked?

Comment: @MJP No it is not the same. It is not hard to prove that that equation is true. I ran some code in Mathematica and it also shows that it is true. You can use IBP to prove it.

Comment: Thanks, so are my two parts $f(x)$ and the part that follows? Or should I multiply first and then integrate by parts the two integrals of the sum?

Comment: @MJP Try both and you will quickly find out which one will work and which one don't.